# Trying To Redirect A Share From One Server To A Share On A Different Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, filesystems, network-share, share

I have a Windows 2008R2 File Server that has multiple shares. What I would like to do is in some way redirect some (not all), of the shares to a different file location.

For some of the shares, the data would be housed on a different file share on a different server, while the user would still input the original name when accessing the data.

Why? We have multiple data processes that would not work correctly if we changed the server name.

**Example illustrating current environment and wanted result:**

### **Current Environment**

**.User Enters  Data  | File Share where Data Housed**

\\SERVER1\Share1 | \\SERVER1\Share1

\\SERVER1\Share2 | \\SERVER1\Share2

### **Wanted Behavior**

**.User Enters  Data  | File Share where Data Housed**

\\SERVER1\Share1 | \\SERVER1\Share1

\\SERVER1\Share2 | \\SERVER2\Share2

Comment: You could (ridiculously) have the data robocopied with /MIR between the shares  But that's pretty silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this. You can DFS to have a unified namespace independent of servers, but you have to be using the namespace, which you're not.

If you were retiring Server1, you could have Server2 answer to either name (Server1 and Server2), but you're not doing that, either.

Lesson learned : Don't hard-code server names into code. Use an alias and/or a config file that won't break when you use it to change the config.

Comment: Implement DFS now so that you won't have this issue in the future.  Use it for everything.